# Load balancer setup on Amazon Web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, windows-server

I have an application on an Windows server EC2 with an SQL server for our database.
What I would like to do is an load balancer so the application won't fail due to overload.
I have a couple of questions that Im not certain about it.

1. I believe that i need to create an image of my current instance and duplicate it. my problem is that my database is based on my current instance so it would duplicate my database as well. 
   Do I need another instance just for my database?
   If yes, then it means that I need a total of 3 instances. 2 for the application and 1 for the database. 
   In this case I need to change my application to connect to the new instance database instead of the current database.

After all that happens I need to add a load balancer.

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using RDS (http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) for this. This way you don't have to worry about the database server and just host your application server on EC2 instances. Your AMI will then contain just the application server and thus when you scale up you will be launching additional app servers only and not database servers.

Since you are deploying a .NET application, I would also recommend taking a look at Elastic Beanstalk (http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) since it will really help to make auto scaling much easier and your solution will scale up/down as well as self-heal itself.

As far the load balancer is concerned, you can either manually update your load balancer will the new instances of your application server or you can let your auto scale script do it for you. If you go for ElasticBeanstalk, then Elastic Beanstalk will take care of adding/removing instances to/from your Elastic Load Balancer for you on its own.

Comment: So basically what you advice is to have an RDS to host my database, an Instance for the application and an elastic beanstalk that will automatically add/remove instances for load balancing? Is that correct?

Comment: RDS hosts your database correct. However if you are using Elastic Beanstalk, then you will not need to setup an instance for your .NET application. Elastic Beanstalk will automatically create instances for your application and will also remove them when they are not needed. basically beanstalk will take care of scaling your instances.

Comment: How would you compare using Elastic beanstalk in compare to using different instances for the application and for the database using a load balancer cost wise?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk by itself does not cost anything. Elastic Beanstalk is basically a collection of different amazon services. When you set it up you choose what features you want (load balancing, auto scaling, etc) and based on that you will get charged. In other words, if you were to setup all the services by yourself, it would cost you the same as it would have Elastic Beanstalk set it up. The difference is that Elastic Beanstalk does the configuration for you automatically rather than you having to learn everything and set it up yourself. Contd due to character limit....

Comment: As for the load balancer, I am guessing you mean running it on RDS vs running it on an instance you setup yourself. For RDS there is definitely a cost impact on top of the instance rates. So running a database on an instance yourself will definitely be cheaper than running it on RDS. However with RDS you get the benefit of it being a managed service. That means that you do not have to worry about configuration, maintenance, etc since AWS takes care of it automatically. So you do not have to worry about things like down time, crashes, backups, etc. Hope this answers your question?